# Creating an arch of list items (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a list of items which have a background image (via CSS) and some text.  The simple markup is as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
    etc...
</ul>
```

Imagine that each list item is a square.  Is there an easy way to display these as a semi-circle? i.e.

```
   [][]
 []    []
[]      []
```

Now to make this slightly more complicated there is one variable - the number of list items is unknown, so I need to work this out on the fly. I can work out the width each list item preety easily, so that it looks correct on the x-xis, I'm just having trouble with the y-axis.

Any help gratefully receieved.

Thanks for your time
Sniffer

Comment: I have no idea what you mean about happy faces and sad faces, can we see what you have?

Comment: `:o)` vs. `:o(`, I guess, but you need a sketch or something.

Comment: I mean semi-circle as in 'n' rather than 'u'.  Does that help?

Comment: @Sniffer no :) Please draw a sketch.

Comment: Edited original question to add layout.

Comment: What would be the order of items ? Clockwise ?

In other words using your sketch would it be : first line items 6 and 1, second line items 5 and 2, third line items 4 and 3 OR first line items 1 and 2, second line items 3 and 4, third line items 5 and 6 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arch is divided up into `item_count-1` slices, an entire circle is 2Pi radians, you are only using a semi-circle (1Pi).  Divide the total (1Pi) by the number of slices (item_count) and multiply the Sin of that by the height of the arch.

in Javascript:

```
for(var i=0; i<item_count; i++){
  var angle=Math.PI/(item_count - 1),
      y=(1-Math.sin(angle * i))*arch_height;
  //set the items CSS 'top' property to y
}
```